# Saving floats to a file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I have calculated the mean values of several lists. Now I would like to save the data to a txt or csv file. Here's my approach:

```
k=range(8,15)
for i in k:
    q=range(i)
    g=mean(q)    
    print g        
    savetxt('mean_values.txt', g)
```

But this gives me `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I think it's because `savetxt` needs an array, but `g` conatins floats.
But even when I define an array `g_`, I end up with the same Error:

```
k=range(8,15)
for i in k:
    q=range(i)
    g=mean(q)    
    g_=array(g)    
    print g_
    savetxt('mean_values.txt', g_)
```

Where's the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first attempt you are trying to save a `numpy.float64` variable, and documentation says that [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) expects an array_like object.

In your second attempt you missed the brackets to specify a matrix `g_=array([g])`, however if you save the txt inside the loop you will be overwriting your output file each time.

I guess this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np

g = list()
k = range(8,15)
for i in k:
    q = range(i)
    g.append(np.mean(q))

np.savetxt('myfile.txt', np.array(g), fmt='%.2f')
```

Output of `myfile.txt`:

```
3.50
4.00
4.50
5.00
5.50
6.00
6.50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myFile = open("mean_values.csv","w")
myFile.write("ID" + "," + "Mean Value" +"\n") //column headers
k=range(8,15)
for i in k:
    q=range(i)
    g=str(mean(q))   
    myFile.write(str(i) + "," + g +"\n")
myFile.close()
```

should give you 2 columns when opened in excel.  One with the ID one with the mean value

Answer (score 0):

Use `(g,)` instead of `g` to make it a tuple containing one float.

Comment: that will print only the mean value of the last list in the txt file. I'd like to have a list with all the mean values.